# Adaptive card speech capabily in Web-chat

Tags: botframework, azure-cognitive-services, adaptive-cards

I have created a bot with an adaptive card with speak property set.

```
AdaptiveCard card = new AdaptiveCard()
        {
            Body = new List<CardElement>()
            {
                new Container()
                {
                    Speak = "<s>Hello!</s><s>Are you looking for a flight or a hotel?</s>",
                    Items = new List<CardElement>()
                    {
                        new ColumnSet()
                        {
                            Columns = new List<Column>()
                            {
                                new Column()
                                {
                                    Size = ColumnSize.Auto,
                                    Items = new List<CardElement>()
                                    {
                                        new Image()
                                        {
                                            Url = "https://placeholdit.imgix.net/~text?txtsize=65&txt=Adaptive+Cards&w=300&h=300",
                                            Size = ImageSize.Medium,
                                            Style = ImageStyle.Person
                                        }
                                    }
                                },
                                new Column()
                                {
                                    Size = ColumnSize.Stretch,
                                    Items = new List<CardElement>()
                                    {
                                        new TextBlock()
                                        {
                                            Text =  "Hello!",
                                            Weight = TextWeight.Bolder,
                                            IsSubtle = true
                                        },
                                        new TextBlock()
                                        {
                                            Text = "Are you looking for a flight or a hotel?",
                                            Wrap = true
                                        }
                                    }
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            },
            // Buttons
            Actions = new List<ActionBase>() {
                new ShowCardAction()
                {
                    Title = "Hotels",
                    Speak = "<s>Hotels</s>",
                    Card = GetHotelSearchCard()
                },
                new ShowCardAction()
                {
                    Title = "Flights",
                    Speak = "<s>Flights</s>",
                    Card = new AdaptiveCard()
                    {
                        Body = new List<CardElement>()
                        {
                            new TextBlock()
                            {
                                Text = "Flights is not implemented =(",
                                Speak = "<s>Flights is not implemented</s>",
                                Weight = TextWeight.Bolder
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        };
```

I am then using this bot from the web-chat control and using Microsoft Cognitive services. Here is the integration code:-

```
const speechOptions = {
    speechRecognizer: new CognitiveServices.SpeechRecognizer({ subscriptionKey: 'YOUR_COGNITIVE_SPEECH_API_KEY' }),
    speechSynthesizer: new CognitiveServices.SpeechSynthesizer({
      gender: CognitiveServices.SynthesisGender.Female,
      subscriptionKey: 'YOUR_COGNITIVE_SPEECH_API_KEY',
      voiceName: 'Microsoft Server Speech Text to Speech Voice (en-US, JessaRUS)'
    })
  };
```

I am using my Cognitive Services API key here.

Q.1) I'm invoking the adaptive card through speech. My expectation is that when the card is delivered, it should read out the content within the SSML tags. But that isn't happening.The adaptive card is simply delivered without voice.

Q.2) For any text content that is delivered through context.PostAsync(), it is read aloud by the web-chat. But I was expecting it to be read aloud only if we use context.SayAsync().

Please help me understand this behavior and how I can deliver the adaptive card with speech. Thanks!

Comment: Related GitHub issue: https://github.com/Microsoft/BotFramework-WebChat/issues/894

Comment: A new release of WebChat was done just last night.  Please try that.  Also, it also looks like you are using an older version of AdaptiveCards.  The .Speak property is being deprecated except for the one on the AdaptiveCard itself.  Please switch to the latest: https://www.nuget.org/packages/AdaptiveCards/

Comment: `speak` was actually removed on individual elements during the preview. As of 1.0 `speak` only exists on the root `AdaptiveCard` itself. Please see if that helps